# Pine script: Run code block only once in historical data

Tags: pine-script

In pine script how do I run a particular code block only once per bar.

```
barstate.isnew // This runs only once in realtime case which is the current bar
But for historical data which is previous bars it is true on each tick, so how can I achieve this for historical data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your code will only run once per historical bar.

> When a Pine script is loaded on a chart it executes once on each
> historical bar using the available OHLCV (open, high, low, close,
> volume) values for each bar. Once the script’s execution reaches the
> rightmost bar in the dataset, if trading is currently active on the
> chart’s symbol, then Pine studies will execute once every time an
> update occurs, i.e., price or volume changes.

See the Pine [Execution Model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) for details.
So, what you're asking for is already the default behavior of Pine Script.

**Edit 1**
In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636349/pine-script-run-code-block-only-once-in-historical-data/67636658?noredirect=1#comment119551467_67636658)

Ah, you mean execute only once per real-time bar.
You'll need to use the [`varip`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_varip) keyword for that instead of `var`.
`varip` is similar to the `var` keyword, but variables declared with `varip` retain their values between the updates of a real-time bar.

This is a fairly new keyword that was released in [March 2021](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Release_notes.html?highlight=varip#march-2021).
An extensive explanation and example script on the usage of `varip` can be found in [this article](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/).

The example code below increases a counter on every "update tick" of the realtime bar.

```
//@version=4
study("")

varip int updateNo = na

if barstate.isnew
    updateNo := 1
else
    updateNo := updateNo + 1

plot(updateNo, style = plot.style_circles)
```

You could add a variable to that to achieve what you want, like this:

```
//@version=4
study("")

varip int  updateNo   = na
varip bool hasBeenRun = false

if barstate.isnew
    updateNo   := 1
    hasBeenRun := true
else
    if not hasBeenRun
        updateNo := updateNo + 1

plot(updateNo, style = plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: No the script runs for each data update of our security right, like if I'm ploting close if price of security moves it will call the script again and re evaluate all stuff right? But I want the code to run only once per timframe.period of chart. If it's 15 mins chart I want the code to run once in that 15mins

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer.